# trigger('RefreshView') problems with pagination

Tags: 7, views, ajax

Colleagues, can you please advise: there is a views with enabled ajax and pagination, there is a form on the page (also ajax, but not views), which makes changes to the displayed views values. To update the views with the values after the form's ajax processing, I use $(".view-name").trigger('RefreshView'); Everything works fine, but there's a nuance - pagination, specifically, no matter which page we were on, Refresh always redirects to the first page. Any thoughts on where to look for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long time  bug in views. I remember I just had a lot of trouble with it on a web site years ago. Take a look at this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3100826

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Looked at the material on the link. there is another problem.